# Why does system downloads Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven everytime in a new workspace?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

Why does system retrieve Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven everytime I run `mvn appengine:devserver` in new project? This process takes a lot of time because of large size. Moreover I have already downloaded Google App Engine Java SDK. I have added the `<sdk>/bin`

in PATH environment variable.

Following are the messages in my terminal.

> [INFO]
>
> [INFO] <<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.7:devserver (default-cli) @ project-ear <<<
>
> [INFO]
>
> [INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.7:devserver (default-cli) @ project-ear ---
>
> [INFO]
>
> [INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Running Development Server
>
> [INFO]
>
> [INFO] Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven
>   Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.8.7/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.7.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting the server, `pom.xml`  in the main application directory should be modified so that  inside the  element points to the installed App Engine SDK version.

```
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<appengine.target.version>1.9.5</appengine.target.version>
</properties>
```

In the above code, version is to be mentioned in the `<appengine.target.version>` tag.

Comment: what to do please can you elaborate??

Comment: it is not even downloading sdk it stucks, i dont know y?

Comment: I've zip file downloaded, so how can i link this file to the maven?

Comment: @android-mantra add <maven-dir-path>/bin to your PATH environment variable

Comment: @vishalaksh I've installed appengine sdk to maven still it's downloading sdk. how should I stop it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already downloaded the SDK zip file install it to maven as following. 
Change file name and version as required.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=appengine-java-sdk-1.9.36.zip -DgroupId=com.google.appengine
    -DartifactId=appengine-api-1.0-sdk -Dversion=1.9.36 -Dpackaging=zip
```